Failed to build Realm in React Native Expo
when I run yarn install, I get the error
➤ YN0007: │ realm@npm:12.11.1 [22b34] must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
every time... so I cannot build through eas
Could anyone help, please?

Try to rebuild Project(Anroid/iOS) and install latest build.
Reason: there is native changes are there for Realm for that after add lib need to install new build.

What do you mean by install new build? I prebuild every time after I install all my packages, but it still raises that error..
